# Script to hide empty categories works but not with products without stock

Tags: category

I have this script to hide empty categories:

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array('gt'=>2));

foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $products = $category->getProductCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    if(!$products->count()) {
        echo $category->getName().'-';
        $category->setIsActive(0);
    } else {
        $category->setIsActive(1);
    }
    $category->save();
}
```

It hides categories with only de-activated products. But how can i extend this with a filter on products which have stock management, but are out of stock?

Answer (score 0):

The Status that you are looking at is wether or not the product is Enabled, not wether or not it is in stock. Since you want to know if its managed or not and currently in stock you will want to join the product against the stock information.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// Join The inventory stock and product collections together
$collection->joinTable(
    array('inv' => 'cataloginventory/stock_item'),
    'product_id = entity_id',
    array("stock_status" => "is_in_stock","manage_stock")
)->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status');

foreach($collection as $_item) {
    if($_item->getManageStock()) {
        // Stock is Managed 
    }
    if ($_item->getStockStatus()) {
        // Is in Stock 
    }

    if ($_item->getManageStock() && $_item->getStockStatus()) {
        // Is a managed stock item that is currently in stock. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I combine these? If a categorie has no active products and no "Stock managed" products in stock, the categorie has to be disabled.

Comment: Hello, if the count on the collection of products is 0 then there is no products, so a straight forward if statement can handle that check.